# I need a query in Mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help with a query for Sql Injection test(please):

My code:

```
 <?php
$conexion = @mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
mysql_select_db("sqli");

if ( isset($_GET['id']) ) {

    $user_id    = $_GET['id'];
    $query      = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $user_id LIMIT 1";
    $result     = mysql_query($query) or die('No!');
    //$result     = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
    $row        = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if ( $row['rol'] == 'admininstrator' ) {
        next_lvl();
    }

}

if ( isset($_GET['name']) ) {
    $name= strip_tags($_GET['name']);
    echo "<h1>Hello $name</h1>";
}

            ?>
    <body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code of sql injection, but, i need access to function "next_lvl()".

I try this: http://localhost/sqli/sql.php?uid=4+or+1=1 and print the next error:
Notice: Undefined index: rol in E:\Programs\wamp\www\Sqli\sql.php on line 24

Thanks.

Comment: does your table have a column called rol?

Comment: The error is saying that there is no `$row['rol']`. `var_dump($row)` will help you ascertain that the result has what you are expecting.

Comment: I do not have to modify the code, just as I must do the test. On the other hand, if there is a field called role.

Comment: Using sql injection, accessing that function is a "level" style.

Comment: I worked perfectly, now, if I did not have the column in the users table, how would I do the injection? @chris85

Comment: I mean one, and my users table exists the column "role", however, if i had to do a sql injection with that code and there was no "role" column, how could I do it?

Comment: Perfect, it was not my question any more, thank you Chris, here how can i choose you as the best answer?

Comment: `uid` is not equal to `id`. `$_GET['id']` is never set.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated and your query opens you up to SQL injection. You're not using SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Your `4 or 1 = 1` is a valid query however it doesn't ensure that the `rol` is an `admininstrator`. You need that for the PHP to execute the function you want. If you use:

```
id && rol = 'admininstrator'
```

(but URL encoded) you can be sure the `rol` is an `admininstrator`.

To stop this from being possible you should upgrade to `mysqli` or `pdo` and use parameterized queries. If you have to maintain the `mysql_` driver you could cast the ID as an `int`.

```
$user_id = (int)$_GET['id'];
```